Session drops out when using mod_rewrite and not going to index.php
So I am using mod_rewrite.
I call a session create file on every page load. It creates a session with a couple of variables.
When I go to a subfolder, ie: https://domainname.com/merchants/ it also uses the same session create file to create the same session and variables.
Then when I go from the domain folder, ie: https://domainname.com/merchants/ and go to the domain folder https://domainname.com/, but do not specify a php file such as https://domainnamd.com/index.php, the session drops out.
But when I got from the subfolder, to https://domainname.com/index.php, the sessions persists with all the variables.
I suspect that when using mod rewrite and going to the domain folder without aiming at a specific file, it is the equivalent of doing a redirect in which session start is not called on the in between page, and we end up here https://domainname.com/ without our session variables and a new session ID.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
My .htaccess file (the important bits only):


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost:8080
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    
    Header Set Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(self)
    
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
    
    Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    
    RewriteRule !(\.gif|\.jpe?g|\.png|\.php|\.css|\.js|\.html|\.ihtml|\.htm)$ index.php [nocase,last]


Thank you
I have tried a hundred things to get past this, but still nothing.
** update with session initialisation info. **
The following code is called on an included file on every page. No other session start is anywhere else on the site.

I have also used multiple versions of testing with phprc and php.ini pointing to a session folder, session set path, and session domain, in setting the cookie or session, this has not changed anything. It still does this.
In some cases of testing, it would actually save the session in a custom session folder in the root domain folder, but it would not retrieve that session, it would start a new one instead. 


    session_start();
    $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID = session_id();
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['COOKIE_SESSION_ID']))
    {
    setcookie('COOKIE_SESSION_ID', 
    $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID, $this->EXPIRE_NUM_SECS);    
    }   
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SHOP_SESSION_ID']))
    {
    $_SESSION['SHOP_SESSION_ID'] = $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID;  
    define('SESS_ID',           $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID);
    define('SHOP_SESSION_ID',   $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID);    
    }
    else 
    {           
    define('SESS_ID',           $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID);
    define('SHOP_SESSION_ID',   $this->SHOP_SESSION_ID);
    }


thank you very much for your help.

There is no obvious reason, why / and /index.php should show different behavior. What parameters is the session cookie set with? Does it get shown in the browser dev tools, when you are the root URL?

How are you initialising the session?  Please could you share the relevant bit of PHP code

Sorry, I made an error.
The session is also lost when going from a subfolder to the root folder:
https://domainname.com/merchants/
To
https://domainname.com/home
And the root folder has a page name as above, it still loses the session.
